# Selectable icons by dragging cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to select multiple items as you would on your PC desktop, where you drag your cursor and the transparent box goes over the icons and selects them like this:
[Desktop icon select.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SqYS.gif)

except I need it to be able to start the selection box from anywhere, not have to start dragging from on top of an icon like the above GIF shown at the end of the GIF.

here's the code to modify (I got it off http://jqueryui.com/selectable/): >>uses JQuery<<

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>
    #feedback {
      font-size: 1.4em;
    }
    
    #selectable .ui-selecting {
      background: #FECA40;
    }
    
    #selectable .ui-selected {
      background: #F39814;
      color: white;
    }
    
    #selectable {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 60%;
    }
    
    #selectable li {
      margin: 3px;
      padding: 0.4em;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      height: 18px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#selectable").selectable();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
  </ol>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to change the selector on which you have your **[`.selectable()`](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/)** hooked up to.
In the following example I modify it to run off of `<body>` with `$("body").selectable()`. Note that if you want to only be able to select the `#selectable` elements, you can make use of `filter` in the `.selectable()` function, such as with `filter: "#selectable > li"`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("body").selectable({
    filter: "#selectable > li"
  });
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#selectable li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to have these changes of css on `#selectable`

```
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  padding: 0 40% 0 0;
  width: 100%;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>
    #feedback {
      font-size: 1.4em;
    }
    
    #selectable .ui-selecting {
      background: #FECA40;
    }
    
    #selectable .ui-selected {
      background: #F39814;
      color: white;
    }
    
    #selectable {
      box-sizing: border-box; 
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 40% 0 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #selectable li {
      margin: 3px;
      padding: 0.4em;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      height: 18px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#selectable").selectable();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
  </ol>


</body>

</html>
```